# How to run Java Applet with Node.js as server side?

Tags: java, javascript, html, node.js, applet

I´m trying to insert a Java Applet into a html document suportted by a server Node.js. I put the Applet tag in the html document and put the signed file .jar  on the folder too. When i load the page in the browser and the browser try to load de Applet i receive a message of blocked app.

I know that this is because the Java version needs a exception in the browser, and then i added the exception and i received a new message telling me that an app without sign is trying to execute.

With this message i understand that server Node.js doesnt recognize the sign of the file .jar of my Applet, but its really signed (selfsigned, but signed). And when i accept to execute the app the Applet doesnt work.

After, i tried to execute the same Applet in the same html document and with the same .jar file with an Apache server, and i received some different messages. But finally i add the exception in the broser and when i accept the pop up window the Applet run perfectly.

I put here a image with the diferent messages in Node.js and in Apache:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cw3ula186xj78eg/Process.png?dl=0

I have analized the error with Node.js and i have some messages in the java console and an error relationed with a "magic value" that i dont really understand. I put a image of this errors in the next link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s37e9mr7bkxh1jy/Error%20Node.png?dl=0

I dont know if i have to configure some special parameters in Node.js or it's another kind of error. I have tried to explain my case and i hope someone can help me with this point. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: The problem is that those error dialogs are not English, and the text in the picture cannot be copy/pasted so it can be fed through a translator. In any case I don't see what Node.js has to do with this, applet execution happens entirely on the client. What does this applet do? Does it at any time try to make a HTTP connection back to the server?